# DTerm: How to open into iTerm2 rather than Terminal.app by default?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-lion, terminal.app

In DTerm, one can open a full terminal application by typing <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>↩</kbd> after a command entered at the DTerm prompt.

In a recent release, it is [noted](http://decimus.net/DTerm/release_notes.html) that support has been added for iTerm2 in DTerm via an AppleScript. However, I am unable to find any reference regarding how to enable this.

So, the question: How does one change the default full terminal application in DTerm?

Comment: Current alternative: Copy-paste the command and click into iTerm2 using Go2Shell.

Comment: I'd say, check with their support on how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make iTerm2 default term app. It can be done by clicking on corresponding entry of iTerm's menu.
Then, I suppose, you'll have to reload DTerm and it'll open iTerm app by default.

Answer (score 0):

Time has passed and DTerm has been [open-sourced](https://github.com/bdrister/dterm)! \o/

If you experience an issue with DTerm and a recent version of iTerm2 (maybe [nightly](http://iterm2.com/downloads/nightly/)). That could be the result of iTerm2's new Apple Scripting Bridge.

I have fixed it and here's a [Pull Request](https://github.com/Orangenhain/dterm/pull/2) for it.